# How to use computed method inside foreach in knockout.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm playing with knockout a little bit, and I'm stuck with something. I did the example that you create the first name, the last name and then create a ko.computed to make the fullName. That works ok, but let's say I have an observable array with a lot of objects containing first names and last names. How to use the computed function to create the full name? If i create something like:

```
function vm() {
....


self.fullName = ko.computed(function() {
  return self.names().firstName + "" + self.names().lastName;
}
```

I can't use it because this is a viewmodel method, and inside a foreach binding knockout will look for local methods (in this case, methods of self.names())

Also can't use $root.fullName because then knockout will not retrieve the correct value.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mtfv6q6a/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can call it by assiging a variable to your vm sth. like :

```
    appModel = new vm();
    ko.applyBindings(appModel);
```

and

```
    <h3 data-bind="text: appModel.fullName()"></h3>
```

this works, but would always return undefinedundefined http://jsfiddle.net/mtfv6q6a/1/ because firstName is not a property of names()

you rather need some simple function like:

```
self.returnFullName = function(item) {
    return item.firstName + " " + item.lastName;
};
```

and call it like

```
<h3 data-bind='text: appModel.returnFullName($data); '></h3>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mtfv6q6a/2/

Comment: Does works, but in this case i could just do $root.returnFullName($data). Thanks

Comment: for understanding, you dont call computed functions, computed functions are called automaticaly when a containing observable changes, so

Comment: Thanks for the jsfiddle - with your example I was able to get my code working. By the way, in the loop, you can call $parent.fullName() if you don't want to assign a variable ("appModel") to the model as you did in the first step.

Comment: you´re welcome, glad it helped. You are also right with "$parent" but assigning it to a variable is usefull for some other reasons, imagine you want to `console.log()` all names (no data-bind, just script) you could do it by `console.log(appModel.names())`